# Display KMZ loaded file is not the same as original file in Google Map API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, google-earth, kmz

I have loaded a KMZ file in Google Map API v3 which has detail polygons but the system doesn't show detail polygons and just display one polygon.

Original KMZ file in Google Earth:

[image: Original file in Google Earth]

Displayed KMZ file in Google Map API v3:

[image: Original file in Google Map]

[KMZ File](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27184702/RighTel/Coverages/Tehran_Indoor.kmz)

Does anybody know how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the KMZ file look like?  There are [restrictions on KML/KMZ files in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps), does the same issue exist if you display the file on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com)

Comment: Please see the attached file

Answer (score 1):

All your polygons have the same winding direction.

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/Tehran_Indoor.kmz

To make holes in a polygon the innerBoundaryIs needs to wind in the opposite direction of the outerBoundaryIs that contains it.

[Google map displaying your KML with reversed innerBoundaryIs](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkmz%2FTehran_IndoorRev.kmz&hl=en&ll=35.733694,51.395073&spn=0.209017,0.363579&sll=40.85968,-74.157769&sspn=0.194745,0.363579&t=h&z=12)

[geoxml3 displaying the KMZ (with computed winding direction)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_winding_linktoB.html?lat=35.733963&lng=51.395014&zoom=12&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/Tehran_IndoorRev.kmz)

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply.
I have lot of KMZ file and I want to update them weekly and I wonder if it's necessary  to add the actual lat,lon in my code.
Would you please help me to change my code without mention the related lat,lon on it?
Moreover, I don't have any idea how can I change the winding direction in the polygons on my KMZ file?